Obtaining the Area Formula of a Fundamental Domain from the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem
First of all, sorrying for posting a similar question again but this is the improved version (See reference section).
A special case of Theorem 10.6.4 of Beardon's book about possible shapes of Dirichlet domains have been discussed in the following result from Yiltekin-Karatas's dissertation.

Lemma 1 (Page.9) 
Suppose that $ F $ is a fundamental domain for $ \Gamma $. Then let $ l_1, l_2, l_3 $ be the lengths of the cycles that correspond to the conjugacy classes associated with $ m_1, m_2 $, and $ m_3 $. Also, suppose that there are $ s $ accidental cycles of lengths $ r_1, \ldots, r_s $. We choose any $ p $ in $ F^\circ $ and connect $ p $ to the vertices of $ F $. By the Gauss-Bonnet formula, the area of $ F $ equals:
$ \mu(F) = (l_1 + l_2 + l_3 + r_1 + \ldots + r_s)\pi - 2\pi - 2\pi s - 2\pi \left( \frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{1}{m_2} + \frac{1}{m_3} \right) $

** Note that Theorem 10.6.4 of Beardon's book has the same proof but it doesn't mention Gauss-Bonnet theorem.
Here is the Gauss-Bonnet theorem;

Theorem 8 (Gauss-Bonnet)
Let $ \Delta $ be a hyperbolic triangle with angles $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma $. Then the area of the triangle is:
$ \mu(\Delta) = \pi - \alpha - \beta - \gamma $

My goal is to derive the expression in Lemma 1 myself.
My attempt
To start with, I used the same configuration as Figure 10.6.2 of Beardon. Given the triangle, I chose an interior point $p$ and subdivided each angle (pink ones) as follows;

The purple lines show the H-area of each sub-triangle and the bottome line shows the total H-area.
In the above attempt, I was hoping to arrive at some form which allows me to substitute angles with cycle-lengths to recover the desired expression.
Can someone provide a derivation or explain how cycle-lengths arise in the application of Gauss-Bonnet theorem in Lemma 1?
Reference

Yiltekin-Karatas's dissertation: https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/g/g040.htm
Beardon, Alan F. The geometry of discrete groups. Vol. 91. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.
Previous post that I got the reference of Yiltekin-Karatas's dissertation from Prem.
Origin of a Relation in the Proof of Theorem 10.6.4 in Beardon's Book
Previous version of this post: Derivation of a Fundamental Domain's Area Formula from the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem


I finally found the answer to my question. It was in the lecture notes of Charles Walkden (https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Charles.Walkden/hyperbolic-geometry/hyperbolic_geometry.pdf).
By transforming $ \text{Area}_H(D) = (n - 2)\pi - 2\pi \left( \sum_{j=1}^{r} \frac{1}{m_j} + s \right) $ in the following quote, I think I've arrived the desired expression!
Quote from the notes: Proof of Proposition 21.4.1.

We use the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem (Theorem 7.2.1). Let $E_1, \ldots, E_r$ be the non-accidental elliptic cycles. By Proposition 17.3.1, the angle sum along the elliptic cycle $E_j$ is $ \sum(E_j) = 2\pi m_j $.


Suppose that there are $s$ accidental cycles. (Recall that an elliptic cycle is said to be accidental if the corresponding elliptic cycle transformation is the identity, and in particular has order 1.) By Proposition 17.3.1, the internal angle sum along an accidental cycle is $2\pi$. Hence the internal angle sum along all accidental cycles is $2\pi s$.


As each vertex must belong to some elliptic cycle (either an elliptic cycle with order at least 2, or to an accidental cycle) the sum of all the internal angles of $D$ is given by $ 2\pi \left( \sum_{j=1}^{r} \frac{1}{m_j} + s \right) $.


By the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem (Theorem 7.2.1), we have $ \text{Area}_H(D) = (n - 2)\pi - 2\pi \left( \sum_{j=1}^{r} \frac{1}{m_j} + s \right) $.

Note

Proposition 17.3.1: 
Let $\Gamma$ be a Fuchsian group with Dirichlet polygon $D$ with all vertices in $H$ and let $E$ be an elliptic cycle. Then there exists an integer $m_E \geq 1$ such that $ m_E \sum(E) = 2\pi $.
Moreover, $m_E$ is the order of $E$.

